# Need some debug guidance on VPI connection with legacy simulation flow in Origen

Tags: verilog, origen-sdk

I am attempting to hook Origen-Sim into a legacy simulation flow, and am having some trouble getting the socket connection to work.

For debug purposes I added a new entry into simulator.rb that would allow me to manually launch the simulator:

```
    when :legacy
    #cmd = "sim na_origen2 -makeopts SOCKET='#{socket_id}
    cmd = "echo 'hi!'"
    puts(socket_id)
```

I then run my simulator with +socket+{socket_id}

What I am seeing:

When I do not pass in a socket, the simulator dies with:

```
ERROR: No socket ID given to the simulator
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Origen app!
ncelab: *F,INTERR: INTERNAL EXCEPTION
```

AND Origen just hangs - as expected.

When I *do* pass in the socket, I get the same error *but* Origen then has seen something on the socket but crashes.  Error at EOM.

Full disclosure - because I am running a legacy flow I am using ncsim instead of irun.  To do this I am running with -loadpli libpli.so:origen_startup.  I thought perhaps that the bootstrap in the code was causing it to run twice, but commenting it out had no effect:

```
/// Bootstrap vector, make the simulator execute init() on startup
// void (*vlog_startup_routines[])(void) = { init, 0 };
```

Guidance on debug appreciated! Maybe some simple code to test the connection?

Error log from Origen:

```
/tmp/1699615188824304081984.sock
lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/compatibility_guard.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/compatibility_guard.rb:3
    from lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3:in `require'
    from lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3
    from lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:3:in `require'
    from lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:3
[INFO]       59.654[59.649]  || Generating...  output/example.txt
[INFO]       59.743[0.088]   ||  
[INFO]       59.743[0.000]   || Pattern vectors: 0         
[INFO]       59.743[0.000]   || Execution time : 0.000000
[INFO]       59.743[0.000]   || ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]       59.744[0.001]   || *** NEW FILE *** To save it:  cp output/example.txt .ref/example.txt
[INFO]       59.744[0.000]   || **********************************************************************

COMPLETE CALL STACK
-------------------
Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:11 
origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:367:in `readline'
origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:367:in `get'
origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:486:in `sync_up'
origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:374:in `pattern_generated'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:372:in `block in pattern_close'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:370:in `each'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:370:in `pattern_close'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:199:in `pattern_wrapper'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:133:in `block (10 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:107:in `block (9 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:105:in `block (8 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:103:in `block (7 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:101:in `block (6 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:99:in `block (5 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:95:in `block (3 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:91:in `block in create'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:8:in `invoke'
origen/generator/pattern.rb:89:in `create'
pattern/example.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
origen/generator/job.rb:148:in `load'
origen/generator/job.rb:148:in `run'
origen/generator.rb:31:in `generate_pattern'
origen/application/runner.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in launch'
origen/application/runner.rb:84:in `each'
origen/application/runner.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in launch'
origen/application/runner.rb:140:in `record_invocation'
origen/application/runner.rb:75:in `block in launch'
origen/file_handler.rb:392:in `preserve_state'
origen/application/runner.rb:18:in `launch'
origen/commands/generate.rb:61:in `block in <top (required)>'
origen/commands/generate.rb:41:in `_with_doc_tester'
origen/commands/generate.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
origen/commands.rb:233:in `require'
origen/commands.rb:233:in `<top (required)>'
.origen/gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/origen-0.31.0/bin/origen:184:in `require'
.origen/gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/origen-0.31.0/bin/origen:184:in `<top (required)>'


APPLICATION CALL STACK
----------------------
Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:11 
pattern/example.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:361:in `write': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:361:in `put'
    from origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:485:in `sync_up'
    from origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:514:in `peek'
    from origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:494:in `error_count'
    from origen_sim/lib/origen_sim/simulator.rb:610:in `on_origen_shutdown'
    from .origen/gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/origen-0.31.0/bin/origen:229:in `each'
    from .origen/gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/origen-0.31.0/bin/origen:229:in `ensure in <top (required)>'
    from .origen/gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/origen-0.31.0/bin/origen:230:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like typing in a big 'ol question to get the brain working.  It appears the issue is that the bootstrap function call in libpli.so:origen_startup gets called both during elaboration and simulation.

Resolved this issue by adding a bootstrap function to origen.c:

```
PLI_INT32 bootstrap(p_cb_data data) {
      vpi_printf("Bootstrap Called!\n");
      init();
      return 0;
}
```

Then change the -libpli to libpli.so:bootstrap

This seems to resolve this issue, though I don't have it completely working yet.  I will submit a PR with this once I get everything else working.